# RHPAM WorkItemHandler not finding database driver

Tags: sql-server, driver, jbpm

I created a WorkItemHandler for RHPAM 7 which has to connect to a ms sqlserver database; the meaningful part in the WorkItemHandler descriptor goes like this

```
mavenDepends = {
                @WidMavenDepends(group = "org.jbpm.contrib", artifact = "cea-assignation-workitem", version = "7.39.0.Final"),
                @WidMavenDepends(group = "com.microsoft.sqlserver", artifact = "mssql-jdbc", version = "8.4.1.jre11")
        }
```

the process in which this work item handler is used has a dependency like this

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>8.4.1.jre11</version>
    </dependency>
```

and i can see the artifact in the .m2 folder of the server.

But the problem is that when the work item handler is triggered i get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;DatabaseName=DB;"
```

I guess the work item handler cannot access the artifact, but i don't know why since the dependency is there

Please help

Comment: By the way, the version i am using in my local development environment is 7.39.0.Final-redhat-00005 and everything works here, but the version in the server i am trying to solve the problem for is 7.39.0.Final-redhat-00007

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the Microsoft SQL Server module in your EAP? If you’re trying to connect Microsoft SQL Server from your application, you must have a data source defined in your EAP `standalone.xml` profile. This will require the Microsoft SQL Server driver. So, adding the Microsoft SQL Server module in EAP will resolve your problem.

Comment: yes, the module exists and is working